# Adding class in a <link> if no pathname is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery

We want to add a class on our the first-child of the link when **window.location.pathname** is **NULL**

the html code is

```
  <nav>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="company.php">Company</a>
    <a href="products.php">Products</a>
    <a href="technical.php">Technical</a>
    <a href="services.php">Services</a>
    <a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
```

and the URL is *www.nicadpower.com/* doing

```
window.location.pathname.substring(1);
```

Would not result anything except a **NULL**.

After detecting a NULL we want the **$('nav a')** first-child to add the **class="current"**

```
  <nav>
    <a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a>
    <a href="company.php">Company</a>
    <a href="products.php">Products</a>
    <a href="technical.php">Technical</a>
    <a href="services.php">Services</a>
    <a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `window.location.pathname.substring(1);` gives you `null` then just use this:

```
if (window.location.pathname.substring(1) == null){
  $('nav a:first-child').addClass('current');
}
```

but... <strike>I don't think it'll give you null, prolly</strike> **it won't** give you `null`, so **you are** better off doing this:

```
if (window.location.pathname.substring(1).length==0){
  $('nav a:first-child').addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: @Steve I don't test every single answer I provide, but just for you: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/qAZ9T/. It **does not** provide `null`

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, that would indeed be better

Answer (score 0):

`pathname` is never `null`, it always contains at least `/` -see the [W3C spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes).

So, you just need to check that the length of the string isn't more than one:

```
if (window.location.pathname.length <= 1) {
  $('nav a:first-child').addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: yap, i already account that one, that is why we placed **substring(1**). thanks dude. ^^

Comment: @DoYouWantaWebsite you've missed the point - taking the substring of a string is a much more expensive test than simply taking its length.  It's also less clear.